# how to display a ifram url in my main url address?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, tags

how can I display iframe website URL in my main URL address bar so please can me tell me how to do this i am trying to do this but when i am display the URL of a iframe webpage was redirect to this link it is possible to display a iframe URL in the main URL address bar

Comment: I don't think that's possible; it would make it SO easy for anybody to spoof any URL. Why do you need to do this?